# Magento Product page open in new tab Target Blank

Tags: magento, tabs, categories, product

I am trying to find a way to open my website product page open in new tab. Please help me.

Comment: Please put in some code here

Comment: please check below code and reply if have any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use custom theme, then check path:

```
app/design/frontend/{your_namespace}/{your_theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

If you use rwd theme, then check path:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

find any anchor link and add traget="_blank"

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
```

change to:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
```

Comment: Nothing happen when i changed the code. I am using custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below list.phtml file into your theme folder and add the HTML attribute

File path is app/design/frontend/**your_package**(base)/**your_theme**(default)/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

**target="_blank"**

find the line

`<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">`

change it to

`<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">`

Do this for list and grid as well...

Comment: Thanks tarun . Its work partial. When i click at product image then it open in new tab but product title still opening in same tab.

Answer (score 0):

For codazon theme, add `target="_blank"` on below file path

`/app/design/frontend/Codazon/unlimited/furniture/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/list-styles/list-style17.phtml`

```
<a href="<?= $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank" class="product photo product-item-photo">
```